# Pass And Return A String Into VB.NET Web Method

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

I am trying to send and return a simple string to a VB.NET web method from Javascript using AJAX. Here is the Javascript/jQuery script I am using:

```
function jQuerySerial() {
//I SET A VARIABLE TO THE STRING I WANT TO PASS INTO MY WEB METHOD
var str = "Hello World";

//AND TRY TO PASS IT INTO MY VB.NET WEB METHOD
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test_WebService.asmx/testWebService",
    data: str,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (e) {
        alert("It worked: " + e);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("There was an error retrieving records: " + e);
    }
});
}//END jQuerySerial
```

And here is the very simple VB.net Web Method. The Web Method does nothing but get the string and then pass it back to Javascript:

```
   <WebMethod( )> _
Public Function testWebService(str As String) As String
    Return str
End Function
```

When I attempt to run this the error: function fires and returns a message saying:

```
"There was an error retrieving records: [object Object]"
```

I have many, many other Web Methods in this same Web Service class that manipulate database records and they all work. But, this is the first one I have ever tried to write using the $.ajax syntax and return something to the calling Javascript so I am completely clueless on whats wrong here.

Any suggestions on how to make this work would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To help you debug the JS, try `console.log(e)` in your `success` & `error` functions instead of `alert`. Because the $.ajax() `error` handler is fired, it's safe to assume the error lies in the JS - try changing your string to valid json before sending (i.e.: `str = {"hello":"world"}`)

Comment: Thank you @WillemLabu for your input. I took your input as well as the information from the link Joshua Whitley provided and solved the problem. I greatly appreciate your assistance. I will post the solution I used shortly.

Comment: Glad I could help. :{D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that you're passing a simple string to the Web Service when it is expecting a JSON object. See this article on common issues with jQuery and ASP.NET web services (specifically item 2):

http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Using the link you provided I changed my input string from: var str = "Hello World"; to: var str = "{ 'str': 'hello world'}"; and the function now returns successfully. Now I get a message: "It worked: [object Object]". Would you know how I can read the returned object so I can parse it back into a string? Thanks

Comment: @Slaks gave me the answer to my second question about how to use the response object. 

ASP.Net WebMethods wrap their return values in a JSON object with a d property. (You can see this in the response body in the browser's developer tools)

You need to write e.d to get the actual value.

Thanks